# getting the URL entered in a jsp

Tags: jsp

I am using spring security where I need to do a login with facebook.

For example if the user wants to see the my account details. For that user has to login so I am redirecting to login form. In this login form I have mentioned the facebook sign in option.

**www.example.com/myCredit.do** if the user enters this url he will be redirected to **www.example.com/login** without going to myCredit page.

I need to somehow store **"www.example.com/myCredit.do"** so that I can redirect after facebook login.

Answer (score 1):

Put the url in session, then you can get url from session after login.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the Url as a String and redirect the request to another page using  [sendRedirect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) method.

This method sends back the response to the browser along with the status code and new page location. You can also use `setStatus()` and `setHeader()` methods together to achieve the same redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a parameter and get it in your **credit page**, if the parameter goes **null** or **empty** then redirect to your credit page by default.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like following

```
www.example.com/login?redirectURL=www.example.com/myCredit.do
```

now, after successful login , redirect according to aforementioned param in URL `redirectURL`